# How to create JSON from Query in PHP

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I have been looking and trying many different ways to create the JSON below from a postgres table using PHP, but did not work, specially to add the "group". Group should be added when there are different date, so it would create groups by date, as the example below. Does anyone know how can I do it?

**EXPECTED:**

```
"t": [

                {
                    "group": "2015-03-25",
                    "list": [{
                        "t": 1,
                        "titulo": "Pages - Multi-Purpose Admin Template Revolution Begins here!",
                        "to": ["David Nester", "Jane Smith"],
                        "time": "5 min. atrás",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 1:33pm",
                        "from": "David Nester",
                        "icone": 1
                    }, {
                        "t": 2,
                        "titulo": "Your site has some very imaginative animation /movement, especially the Sluggo! ",
                        "to": ["Anne Simons"],
                        "time": "45 min. atrás",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 1:33pm",
                        "from": "Anne Simons",
                        "icone": 2
                    }, {
                        "t": 3,
                        "titulo": "Recently ordered a new pair of soccer cleats from your website on June 21",
                        "to": ["Herald Menster"],
                        "time": "13:33",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 1:33pm",
                        "from": "David Nester",
                        "icone": 1
                    }, {
                        "t": 4,
                        "titulo": "Everything here, Made Just for you :)",
                        "to": ["John Doe"],
                        "time": "11:23",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 11:23am",
                        "from": "David Nester",
                        "icone": 3
                    }, {
                        "t": 5,
                        "titulo": "Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication",
                        "to": ["John Doe", "Anne Simons"],
                        "time": "22:33",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 10:33pm",
                        "from": "David Nester",
                        "icone": 2
                    }]
                }, {
                    "group": "2015-03-24",
                    "list": [{
                        "t": 6,
                        "titulo": "Good design is obvious. Great design is transparent",
                        "to": ["John Doe", "Anne Simons"],
                        "time": "13:33",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 1:33pm",
                        "from": "David Nester",
                        "icone": 1
                    }, {
                        "t": 7,
                        "titulo": "Your site has some very imaginative animation /movement, especially the Sluggo! ",
                        "to": ["Anne Simons"],
                        "time": "45 mins ago",
                        "datetime" : "Today às 13:33",
                        "from": "Anne Simons",
                        "icone": 2
                    }, {
                        "t": 8,
                        "titulo": "Aliquam est tellus, fringilla egestas fermentum quis",
                        "to": ["John Doe", "Anne Simons"],
                        "time": "13:33",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 1:33pm",
                        "from": "David Nester",
                        "icone": 2
                    }, {
                        "t": 9,
                        "titulo": "Aliquam est tellus, fringilla egestas fermentum quis",
                        "to": ["John Doe", "Anne Simons"],
                        "time": "13:33",
                        "datetime" : "Today at 1:33pm",
                        "from": "David Nester",
                        "icone": 1
                    }
```

**CURRENT CODE:**

With this code below I get the following result, but it never add different "group", just add the first one:

```
echo '{ "t": [';

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data["group"] = $row["datetime"];
    $data["list"][] = $row; 
};

echo json_encode($data);

echo "]}";
```

**WRONG RESULT:**

```
{
    "t": [
        {
            "group": "2014-09-22",
            "list": [
                {
                    "t": "133640",
                    "titulo": "Some problem",
                    "to": "Erik",
                    "time": "9:30",
                    "datetime": "2014-09-22",
                    "from": "Julian",
                    "icone": "1"
                },
                {
                    "t": "133641",
                    "titulo": "Problems",
                    "to": "Robert",
                    "time": "9:30",
                    "datetime": "2014-09-22",
                    "from": "Julian",
                    "icone": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to push `$data` into a `$tickets` array

```
$tickets = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $data["group"] = $row["datetime"];
  $data["list"] = $row;
  $tickets['tickets'][] = $data;
};

echo json_encode($data);
```

May this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gopakumar! Unfortunately it did not work. I changed $data to $tickets in the last line, but I got "group" repeating every single date. I did not explain so well at the first, but It should be added only when I have diferent group, in other words, different date. Do you have other sugestion? Thanks!

Comment: can I see the query part too?

Comment: Hi Gopakumar, thanks for your interest in help me. Fortunately I solved this problem already. Best regards!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you solved it by yourself. Please put your solution as an answer and make it accepted, so people who may face slimier situation can use your soultion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php
$json = array();    //This is the MAIN array that you'll encode later

$json_tickets = array();        //This is the json tickets, 1st child / parent of all
$json_tickets["list"] = array();

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $new_item = $row;           //Copy $row into a new variable, since you only want to modify $new_item later...

    $new_item["group"] = $new_item["datetime"];
    $json_tickets["list"][] = $new_item;            //keep adding this into a list array
};
$json['tickets'] = $json_tickets;

echo json_encode( $json );
```

Tips:

- Don't mix your variables.
- Don't cheat :)  on this part of your code -> **echo '{ "tickets": [';**
- **All** your table data on that table will show in your JSON result, be careful as it may include sensitive data later on. might be some security issue
- hmm... what else can I put here as tip for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Thanks also for your recommendations, I really appreciate them. I tried your code, but it did not solve my needs. What I need is this: http://pages.revox.io/doc/1.1.0/jquery/email.php - that is the same structure, I just changed the field names.

Comment: Erik, practice writing more readable codes as it will really help you out in the long-run.  I'm just glad you now have a working and that your problem is now solve. Cheers to that

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and than use json_encode php function

```
$data = array(
    "group" => "2015-03-24",
    "list" => array(
        "ticket" => 6,
        "titulo" => "Good design is obvious. Great design is transparent",
        "to" => array("John Doe", "Anne Simons"),
        "time" => "13:33",
        "datetime" => "Today at 1:33pm",
        "from"=> "David Nester",
        "icone"=> 1
    )


    );

echo json_encode($data);
```

this will give you out put like this

```
{"group":"2015-03-24","list":{"ticket":6,"titulo":"Good design is obvious. Great design is transparent","to":["John Doe","Anne Simons"],"time":"13:33","datetime":"Today at 1:33pm","from":"David Nester","icone":1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your current code :

```
$data["group"] = $row["datetime"];
$data["list"][] = $row;
```

overwrites the 'group' and 'list' members of the array, with the next iteration.

You'd have to find a way around it. For example, by doing something like:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $data[]["group"] = $row["datetime"];
   $data[]["list"][] = $row; 
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
   echo echo json_encode($data[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi mike O., thanks for your answer! It did not work. It adds "group": "Hoje, 24 de Março" between { },  when actually it should not be, as the example. Do you have any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account the new array structure. Try that and let me know what you get.